# How can i add my own GIT to drupal-composer/drupal-project

Tags: git, composer-php, drupal-8

i installed the drupal template with

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --no-interaction
```

but now the root dir has a git repo, the one from drupal-composer/drupal-project

what is the correct way to get my own repo working now? do i have to remove the drupal-composer/drupal-project repo and initialize my own or change something? maybe just changing the remote to my own?

help is much appreciated

Comment: Changing remote should be a better option - you should be able to merge upstream changes in the future.

Comment: ye i just did that, thanks @rob006

Comment: @rob006 is it "normal" that i get the repo into the project with composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --no-interaction ? i had to think about that for the first time tbh

Comment: nvm its because the actual drupal issue with the selenium version so the installer fails before he would remove the repo

Comment: Without `--no-interaction` it should ask you whether to remove these files.